# Can I target to framework64 the aspnet_compile when I call SourceAnalyzer - Fortify?

Tags: msbuild, aspnet-compiler, fortify

I'm creating a MSBuild to run Fortify Scan. The commands are:

1) sourceanalyzer -b MYBUILDID devenv SOLUTION.sln /REBUILD Debug

2) sourceanalyzer -b MYBUILDID -scan -f SOLUTION.fpr -format frp

The build log

1)
1.1)Rebuild Start
.....
The solution has been rebuild succeeded. OK

1.2)After that, it runs the aspnet_compiler 
  ***Running: ASPCOMPILE : "-v" "/FortifyBuildId" "-p" "MySite" "-d" "-f" "-c" "-fixednames" "\%USER%\AppData\Local\Fortify\VS2010-5.9\output...."*** 
  Fortify Source Code Analysis Complete

2) **[error]: Build ID "MYBUILDID" doesn't exist**

My build box is a server 2008 x64 because I have sharepoint installed.
I noticed that the sourceanalyzer calls ASCOMPILE pointing to c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework instead of **c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64**. I've tested it running in both framework. With aspnet_compile 64 works fine ("c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler" "-v" "/FortifyBuildID" "-p" "MySite" "-d" "-f" "-c" "-fixednames" "%USER%\AppData\Local\Fortify\VS2010-5.9\output.."

Do you know How I can fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a known issue with a recent version of Fortify SCA.

Please contact Fortify Technical Support to upgrade, downgrade or apply a hotfix as appropriate.

Comment: I have this exact problem, which support number should I call?

Comment: You could email fortifytechsupport@hpe.com or you could try to call +1-844-260-7219